# How to call this network call in retrofit way

Tags: android, retrofit

```
val url = URL("https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=$merchantId&orderId=$orderId")
val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
connection.requestMethod = "POST"
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
connection.doOutput = true
val requestWriter = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
val postData = AnyJSONObject.toString()
requestWriter.writeBytes(postData)
requestWriter.close()
val responseReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream))
responseReader.readLine()?.let { responseData->
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
        onResponse(responseData)
    }
}
responseReader.close()
```

**Above Code is working Fine I just want to convert it to RestApi Call**

**This is how I have tried**

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("initiateTransaction")
@FormUrlEncoded
suspend fun getCheckSum(
    @Query("mid") mid: String,
    @Query("orderId") orderId: String,
    @Field("extraParamsMap") jsonObjectAsString: String
): JsonObject
```

I am not sure that Field is right or what. I have just tried to do it this way.
I don't have much exp with retrofit

Answer (score 0):

I write one example for GET/POST method.

```
@GET("new_market/service.php?action=getsidebar&packageName=com.gameloft.android.ANMP")
Call<ResultData> doReadyRequest();

@POST("stats_mafia_city")
Call<ResultData> doSendClanData(@Header ("bot_secret") String bot_secret, @Header ("Content-Type") String content_type, @Body JsonObject jsonObject);
```